# How do I update a item with specified string in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, updates

So I need to update a item that has the same id(a string) I provide, so I use for-each loop to search the item, how do I update the title, description, and dueDate?
I have one ArrayList of todoItems

```
// REQUIRES: idToFind is an id for an item in the to-do list
// MODIFIES: this
// EFFECTS: updates the to-do item with the specified id in the to-do          list
public void updateTodoItem(String idToFind, String title,
        String description, Date dueDate) {
    for (TodoItem item: todoItems) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idToFind)) {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your TodoItem class has some conventionaly named setters for its fields. You can do as follows

```
// REQUIRES: idToFind is an id for an item in the to-do list
// MODIFIES: this
// EFFECTS: updates the to-do item with the specified id in the to-do          list
public void updateTodoItem(String idToFind, String title,
        String description, Date dueDate) {
    // Declare a TodoItem here (the target your are looking for)
    TodoItem target = null;
    for (TodoItem item: todoItems) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idToFind)) {
            target = item;
            break;


         }
    }
    // After the for we check if we have found the target item
    if (target != null) {
        // Use the setters of your todo object to set the values
        // like
        target.setTitle(title);
        target.setDescription(description);
        target.setDueDate(dueDate);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you make comparison this way: (null != target) ?
Why not (target != null) ??

Comment: @AlexanderDrobyshevsky it has no impact but (target != null) is more classical so I have edited it.

Comment: I just assumed might there is some benefit which I do not know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void updateTodoItem(String idToFind, String title, String description, Date dueDate) {
  for (TodoItem item: todoItems) {
      if (item.getId().equals(idToFind)) {
          item.setTitle(title);
          item.setDescription(description);
          item.setDate(dueDate);
          System.out.println("Item Found!");
          return; // You can also use 'break;'
     }
  }
  System.out.println("Item Is Not Found!");
}
```